# Run phonegap app server on https

Tags: cordova, geolocation

I'm working on a phonegap project. I need to get the geolocation of the user. When I deploy the APK to my android phone, everything is working fine.

Sadly, I can't get it work on my localhost. I start the phonegap server with:

```
phonegap serve
```

After that I open the provieded URL. When trying to get the geolocation, chrome outputs

```
getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
```

All OK so far. Now I wan't the phonegap server to be started under HTTPS that I can get the geolocation. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Running server in HTTPS and accessing it via Cordova app is very much possible in Android. But its little tricky in iOS

Comment: And how to get it work?

Comment: could you post the code what you have tried till now?

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: Not yet, sorry about that

Comment: also trying to run over https, did you find out how